# Cursor Position Defaults to end of the Document in TeXShop

Tags: texshop

I am using TeXShop on Mac OSX and ever since the OS was updated recently (a few months ago), the cursor position defaults to the end of the document instead of the line I was working at. This happens if the TeXShop is idle for like 5 seconds. For the life of me, I can't find a setting in "preferences" to increase the "idle time" (if it is even or thing) or totally stop it. Has anyone encountered this before? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Possibly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/645957/218142

Comment: I have the same problem. In my case it is due to google drive. If your file is located in a google drive folder, stop the synchronization while you are editing your tex file (or save it elsewhere).