# Random cursor jumps to the bottom of a file while editing it with TexShop

Tags: texshop

I have the following problem when editing source files with TexShop:

While typing in a .tex file, and at seemingly random times, the cursor suddenly jumps to the end of the file (so my edits, e.g., newly typed characters, go to the end of the file until I notice and reposition the cursor).

I have tried to fix this with the following with no success:

1. Change the keyboard
2. Deleting and then reinstalling the entire tex package (i.e., MacTex and TexShop)

Did anyone experience this problem and (hopefully) solved it?

Thank you

Gianni

P.S. Note that:

1. I have been using TexShop for more than 10 years on various Macs, and I never had this problem before it started about 6-8 month ago (I can't recall exactly when).
2. I have been using the same 2018 Mac mini for the last 4 years.

Answer (score 4):

As noted elsewhere, it may be that this issue (which I'm also suffering) only occurs with tex files saved on Google Drive. It still shouldn't occur, of course.

To clarify, what happens to me is:

- TeX files stored locally on my hard drive: the random cursor jumps do not occur.
- TeX files stored inside the Google Drive folder (synchronized to the cloud, obviously): the random cursor jumps occur. Quite regularly, several times during an editing session. Which is quite annoying.

One can of course quit Google Drive or pause synchronization while working in TexShop, and switch it back on when one's done.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

Since this cursor jumping occurs only for your tex files that are stored in Google Drive (GD), it is very likely that GD file synchronization is indeed the culprit.

For me the problem started to occur after I replaced Google's Backup and Synch app with the Drive desktop app that supplanted it (some time in the Fall of 2021).

I am afraid that this is such a niche bug for Google that they will not try to fix it.

Is there a way to alert the TexShop developers about this problem? (May be they can fix it on the TexShop editor end.)

Comment: I also experience this issue, with google drive and texshop.